# Removing Extra Files When Uninstalling WPF ClickOnce Application

Tags: c#, wpf, clickonce

I have a WPF application published via ClickOnce. When deleting it, I also need to delete some files that are no longer needed by the user.

ClickOnce doesn't seem to support adding custom install or uninstall actions.

Please advise some installer that would support custom uninstallation actions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest Inno Setup, that supports a lot of scripting and is open source. (https://jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php)

It will allow you to perform an action like:

```
[UninstallDelete]
Type: filesandordirs; Name: "{localappdata}\<my game folder>"
```